# ``rails server` throws error "require': cannot load such file -- execjs (LoadError) "

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby 2.0.0p576 (2014-09-19 revision 47628) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.1.6

I Just ran rails new projectname and bundle install and When I attempt to start the WEBrick server it throws the following at me:

```
 rails s
    /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: already initialized constant ActionController::Parameters::NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
    /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: previous definition of NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS was here
    /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: already initialized constant ActionController::Parameters::NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
    /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:106: warning: previous definition of NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS was here
    /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- execjs (LoadError)
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `require'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `each'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block in require'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
        from /home/giri/test123/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/giri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This is my Gem file and ruby 2.0

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

Comment: looks like `execjs` gem gives error.

Comment: Are you sure `bundle install` succeeded without errors?  Seems like the native extension for execjs might not have installed?

Comment: Do you have node.js installed?

Comment: yes node installed